# Xunit IClassFixture Not Injected in Linux

Tags: .net-core, xunit

Super simple test setup:

```cs
    public class UiTests : IClassFixture<UiFixture>
    {
        private readonly IWebDriver _driver;

        public UiTests(UiFixture fixture)
        {
            _driver = fixture.Driver;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test()
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:5000/");

            _driver.PageSource.Should().Contain("Hello");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Another()
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:5000/");

            _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("html")).Text.Should().Be("Hello World!");
        }
    }

    public class UiFixture : IDisposable
    {
        private Process _webServerProcess;

        public UiFixture()
        {
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless", "no-sandbox");
            Driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
                LaunchWebServer();

            WaitForWebServer();
        }

        public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_webServerProcess != null && !_webServerProcess.HasExited)
                _webServerProcess.Kill();
        }

        private void LaunchWebServer()
        {
            _webServerProcess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "..", "..", "..", "..", "Web"),
                    FileName = $"dotnet.exe",
                    Arguments = "run",
                    UseShellExecute = true,
                },
            };
            _webServerProcess.Start();
        }

        private void WaitForWebServer()
        {
            var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            var result = socket.BeginConnect("localhost", 5000, null, null);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(30000, true);
            if (socket.Connected)
                socket.EndConnect(result);
            else
                socket.Close();
        }
    }
```

Runs on my windows box great:

```
> dotnet test
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.

Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:     2, Skipped:     0, Total:     2, Duration: 190 ms - Tests.dll (netcoreapp3.1)
```

But when running in my docker image in CI:

```
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.00] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.3+1b45f5407b (64-bit .NET Core 3.1.10)
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.66]   Discovering: Tests
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.69]   Discovered:  Tests
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.69]   Starting:    Tests
Starting ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.107 (87a818b10553a07434ea9e2b6dccf3cbe7895134-refs/branch-heads/4515@{#1634}) on port 36909
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.84]       System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:36909/session timed out after 60 seconds.) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: UiFixture fixture)
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.84]       ---- OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:36909/session timed out after 60 seconds.
[xUnit.net 00:01:00.84]     Tests.UiTests.Another [FAIL]
```

Any idea what's going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a misleading error. It is actually something going wrong with ChromeDriver while newing up the fixture, so I guess it can't be injected.